# How to create user in database manually in Yii2?

Tags: database, yii2, registration

I do import of users from a csv file to the database. In csv file I have some kinda username and password string. So how do I create a new user manually? 
As I understand I need to `getPasswordHash` and `generateAuthKey` (last one generates random string). But probably I loose something important since when I try to log in I get an error that Username or Password is incorrect. Did anyone ever experienced such situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, After importing CSV to database; you can use Yii2's default signup feature for adding new entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set an active status of new User. You should check it in **Login** method of **User** model in your app, or in **actionLogin** of **SiteController**. For example, in my app the **login** method is:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate() and $this->getUser()->status !== User::INACTIVE_STATUS) {
       return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you show your code we can help you faster)

So if you are importing a list of users from a csv file, you will probably process this in a loop, try:

```
foreach ($csv_data as $user_data) {
   $user = new User();
   $user->setPassword($password);
   $user->username = $user_data->username // or anything else, depending on your code
   $user->status = 1  // or = User::STATUS_ACTIVE, depending on your code
   $user->save();
}
```

Comment: I do batch insert, because csv file contains like 40 thousand of users and function `setPassword` uses `generatePasswordHash` which takes almost 1 second to generate hash and if I import 40 thousand of users it would take around 11 hours, so I temporary set same password for each user. 
But I didn't set user status, you must be right. Thanks.

Comment: @khandaniel Correct. So check it and put this answer is usefull if it helped please)

Answer (score 2):

This should be the minimum required in your case. `$username` and `$password` are raw values taken from the CSV. Remember that there will be validation applied.

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = $username;
$user->setPassword($password);
$user->generateAuthKey();

return $user->save();
```